# Open Refine - Add another file to the existing Project

Tags: openrefine

I've imported a CSV file to OR (Open Refine). Since the CSV file I have contains over 200,000 records, I've decided to create separate files, since uploading the large file wouldn't work in my computer (takes too long, not even sure if it is actually importing). I was able to create three .csv files out of the single file (large).

I've successfully imported each of the .csv files but now I want to import all three into one project in OR. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 4):

Add the three file into one zip archive and create a project from this archive.
Refine will unzip the file and detect the three files. Keep the three file selected, Refine will append the data in a new project.

Please note that each file should have the same header order and number of columns or fields will get mixed up.